# Why can't I read a int value after char value in Java?

Tags: java

I have created a simple Java application using `readLine()` of `BufferedReader`. The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
class demo_data
{
    public static void main(String hh[])throws Exception
    {
        char c=' ';
        int i=0;
        String name="";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter char:");
        c=(char)br.read();
        System.out.print("Enter String:");
        name=br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter value:");
        i=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("\tChar:"+c+"\tName:"+name+"\tValue:"+i);
    }
}
```

My problem is that after reading character value, the string statement is skipped and I'm not able to read the value for variable name. If I read a `char` value and then try to read `int` value it throws a `NumberFormatException`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

[`BufferedReader#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), reads a single character from your input. It does not read the `linefeed` at the end of the input.

So, your linefeed goes as input to the `br.readLine` you have after your `br.read`. Now, if you enter a `string` for the `2nd br.readLine`, it is actually goind to the 3rd one. And hence that Exception.

So, your `name` variable will contain a `linefeed - \n`, and the string which you passed for `name` goes to your `int i`.

**Workaround: -**

Try adding an empty `br.readLine` after `br.read()` to consume the left over linfeed: -

```
c=(char)br.read();
br.readLine();  // Add an empty `br.readLine here.
System.out.print("Enter String:");
name=br.readLine();
```

Or, you can also go with [@Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304140/1679863) below

Answer (score 0):

The call to `readLine()` immediately returns because of the `newLine` that will still be in the buffer after you entered the first `char`.

Add an extra `br.readLine()` to fix this:

```
    System.out.print("Enter char:");
    c=(char)br.read();
    br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter String:");
    name=br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

In each case you are really reading a line at a time not just one character and one number.

```
    System.out.print("Enter char:");
    char c = br.readLine().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Enter String:");
    String name = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter value:");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```